# How to get threshold value used by auto threshold Plugin

Tags: imagej

I have the following code, where I read images from directory and use ImageJ Auto Threshold plugin to segment my images.

```
dir = getDirectory("path");
list = getFileList(dir);

for (i=0; i<list.length; i++)
{
   if (endsWith(list[i], ".tif")) 
   {
        open(dir + list[i]);
        run("8-bit");
        run("Gaussian Blur...", "sigma=2");
        setAutoThreshold("Otsu dark");
        run("Convert to Mask");
        saveAs("TIFF", dir+list[i]);
        close();
    }
}
```

I would like to get the threshold value using **"Otsu dark"** method, and modify that value (e.g. scale it by a factor) and apply it to my images for segmentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an ImageJ macro, use the `getThreshold(lower,upper)` and `setThreshold(lower,upper)` methods ([here](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#setThreshold)'s the documentation).

Your code would look like this then:

```
dir = getDirectory("path");
list = getFileList(dir);
factor = 1.5;

for (i=0; i<list.length; i++)
{
   if (endsWith(list[i], ".tif")) 
   {
        open(dir + list[i]);
        run("8-bit");
        run("Gaussian Blur...", "sigma=2");
        setAutoThreshold("Otsu dark");
        getThreshold(lower,upper);
        setThreshold(lower,upper*factor);
        run("Convert to Mask");
        saveAs("TIFF", dir+list[i]);
        close();
    }
}
```

If you plan to do more complicated things, consider using another [scripting language](http://fiji.sc/Scripting_comparisons) like the ones provided by [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/Fiji).